# setExtremes event handler being called an increasing number of times each trigger?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graph, highcharts, react-highcharts

I'm trying to add an event handler to setExtremes for the X Axis. However, this event handler gets called more than once for each zoom action, and whenever the chart is redrawn, the number of times this event will get triggered increases.

When I have something similar to the following:

```
xAxis: {
  ...options.xAxis,
  events: {
    setExtremes: event => console.log('setExtremes'),
    afterSetExtremes: event => console.log('afterSetExtremes'),
  },
},
```

My console gets flooded with both calls. If I trigger enough chart updates, the console looks like this (notice each console.log is being run 23 times).
[image]

I've looked through the Highcharts documentation, as well as their forum and other Stack Overflow questions trying to find something relating to my problem, but nothing seems relevant to this issue.

What should I do to fix an issue like this?

## EDIT:

We are using the map extension to highcharts-react-official

```
require('highcharts/modules/map')(Highcharts);
```

This seems to only happen on the mousewheel zoom handler as an on click handler only fires once regardless of how many times the graph has refreshed

Comment: Are you using a library? Can you provide more context and code please?

Comment: yes we are using the highcharts library with the highcharts-react-official wrapper. Basically every time the graph graph redraws the event handler is called an increasing amount of times. The first time the graph redraws, any zoom events fire the event handler once, second time its twice, third time 3 times...

Comment: Hi @Root0x, Could you reproduce that issue in some online code editor? I tested some basic example with `highcharts-react-official` wrapper and the events were called only once. Example: https://codesandbox.io/s/highcharts-react-demo-wvcii

Comment: I recently noticed similar issue when I had afterSetExtremes.I used setExtremes only.

Comment: No Solutions yet?

Comment: Please see the solution I added here -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068493/react-highcharts-firing-setextremes-event-multiple-times/65871097#65871097

Comment: Does this answer your question? [React Highcharts firing setExtremes event multiple times](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59068493/react-highcharts-firing-setextremes-event-multiple-times)