# React Highcharts firing setExtremes event multiple times

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-highcharts

I am using Highcharts React wrapper in an app using Hooks, when my chart is either loaded or zoomed it fires both setExtremes and setAfterExtremes multiple times each. I've looked through for similar questions but they are related to different issues.

I've reduced the code to the minimum setup, the page is not refreshing, the data is only parsed once and added to the chart once yet, animation is disabled and it's still consistently firing both events 7 times on:
* initial population
* on zoom

Versions: react 16.9, highcharts 7.2, highcharts-react-official 2.2.2

Chart

```
<HighchartsReact
  ref={chart1}
  allowChartUpdate
  highcharts={Highcharts}
  options={OPTIONS1}
/>
```

Chart Options:

```
const [series1, setSeries1] = useState([]);

const OPTIONS1 = {
    chart: {
      type: 'spline',
      zoomType: 'x',
      animation: false
    },
    title: {
      text: ''
    },
    xAxis: {
      events: {
        setExtremes: () => {
          console.log('EVENT setExtremes');
        },
        afterSetExtremes: () => {
          console.log('EVENT sfterSetExtremes');
        }
      },
    },
    plotOptions: {
      series: {
        animation: false
      }
    },
    series: series1
  };
```

Data Population:

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (data1) {
      const a = [];

      _.each(data1.labels, (sLabel) => {
        a.push({
          name: sLabel,
          data: [],
        })
      });

      ... POPULATES DATA ARRAYS...

      setSeries1(a);
    }
  }, [data1]);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Rather the question is old I also faced the same situation. The solution is to move the chart options to a state variable. Then the event will not fire multiple times.

It is mentioned on the library docs. https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts-react -- see the "optimal way to update"

````
import { render } from 'react-dom';
import HighchartsReact from 'highcharts-react-official';
import Highcharts from 'highcharts';

const LineChart = () => {
 
  const [hoverData, setHoverData] = useState(null);
 
  // options in the state
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState({
    xAxis: {
      categories: ['A', 'B', 'C'],
      events: {
        afterSetExtremes: afterSetExtremes,
      },
    },
    series: [
      { data: [1, 2, 3] }
    ],
  });

  function afterSetExtremes(e: Highcharts.AxisSetExtremesEventObject) {
    handleDateRangeChange(e);
  }

  return (
      <div>
        <HighchartsReact
          highcharts={Highcharts}
          options={chartOptions}
        />
      </div>
    )
}

render(<LineChart />, document.getElementById('root'));```
````

Answer (score 0):

Your useEffect is getting fired multiple times probably because you are checking for data1 and data1 is changing. have you tried putting an empty array in your useEffect and see if it is firing multiple times?

if it only fires up once then the problem is that your useEffect is checking for a value that is constantly changing

if it still fires multiple times then there is something that is triggering your useEffect

Comment: hey and thanks, but unfortunately the useEffect is defintely only firing once on intial load which fires the multiple setExtremes THEN when a zoom is actioned the useEffect isn't even called. The events are just fired 7 times.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled the same problem after I SetState in useEffect().
My problem was I did a (lodash) deepcopy of the Whole options.
This also create a new Event every time.

```
  // Create options with afterSetExtremes() event
 const optionsStart: Highcharts.Options = {
         ...
        xAxis: {
            events: {
                afterSetExtremes:  afterSetExtremesFunc,
            }
        },
   ....

  // Save in state
  const [chartOptions, setChartOptions] = useState(optionsStart);

  // On Prop Change I update Series
  // This update deepcopy whole Options. This adds one Event Every time
      React.useEffect(() => {
          
        var optionsDeepCopy = _.cloneDeep(chartOptions);
                optionsDeepCopy.series?.push({
                    // ... Add series data
                });


                setChartOptions(optionsDeepCopy);

      }, [xxx]);
```

The fix is to Only update the Series. Not whole Options.

```
      React.useEffect(() => {
          
        var optionsDeepCopy = _.cloneDeep(chartOptions);
                optionsDeepCopy.series?.push({
                    // ... Add series data
                });


                const optionsSeries: Highcharts.Options = { series: []};
                optionsSeries.series = optionsDeepCopy.series;

                setChartOptions(optionsSeries);

      }, [xxx]);
```